# How to debug UVs exported straight from Blender

Tags: shaders, blender, assets, uv-mapping

I have a model in Blender 2.93. I am exporting it to JSON using [landon](https://github.com/chinedufn/landon)
I am then importing the JSON into a WebGL rendering layer and feeding directly to shaders

The JSON UV export is an array of floats between 0 and 1

The shaders look like:

vert:

```
       precision mediump float;
       attribute vec3 position;
       uniform mat4 model, view, projection;
       attribute vec2 uvs;
       varying vec2 vUv;
       void main() {
          vUv = uvs;
          gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1);
       }
```

frag:

```
      precision mediump float;
      varying vec2 vUv;
      uniform sampler2D tex;
      void main() {
         gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex,vUv);
      }
```

The model in blender looks like:
[image: model in blender]

The model imported in the engine looks like:
[image]

I need ideas for next steps to debug the the UV issue with the texture. The texture seems to load okay but the UVS are off. Is there some conversion step from blender I'm over looking?

**Update #1:**

per @DMGregory in the comments updating the vertex shader to the `gl_Position = vec4(uvs.xy * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)`

The **engine UVS looks like** the following:
[image]

We can compare this to the **UV Mapping from blender**:
[image]

**Update #2 Model loading:**

I am using the [regl](https://regl.party/) webgl frame work to load the model data.
The UVS are in a flat 1D JSON Array and get bound to the shaders as [an regl attribute](https://github.com/regl-project/regl/blob/master/API.md#attributes)

Here is example JSON of the model: https://gist.github.com/kevzettler/648cb509d8f4f5a383696449eced96a2

Comment: Have you tried outputting `vec4(uvs.xy * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)` as your vertex position, to visualize the UV unwrap as seen by your importer? It may also help to show us your model loading function so we can see how you're interpreting the UVs.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @DMGregory I have added the UV unwrap shader output to the post and comparison to the Blender UV map. It seems the engine UV's maybe upside down?. I have also added notes on the Model importing. Let me know if you have further thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Oof. It's hard to say without the wireframe lines, but it looks like there's little to no correlation between the expected UVs and what your shader is receiving. It might help to export a simpler model - like a single quad or standard cube, then walk through each data transformation along the way, comparing the JSON text / debug visualization against a small number of expected values.

Comment: @DMGregory I have a hunch. I have added the JSON of the model to the post. The json includes separate indicies for `position`, `normal`, and `uvs`, based on the post at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/what-is-uvindex-and-how-do-i-use-it-on-opengl  I suspect I need to massage the UVs so that they are arranged in an order that corresponds with the vertice position index. Does this make sense?

Comment: That sounds like a testable hypothesis.